# Static Files and Upload, process, and download in Django

Tags: django

I've made a desktop app in Python to process .xls files with openpyxl, tkinter and other stuff. Now i'm looking to run this App on [www.pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com). I was expecting to make an app to upload the file to the server, process it and then retrieve it changed to the user. But after long months struggling with Django i`ve reached the problem of static media. As I understood Django doesn’t serve files in production mode. Does this means that I can’t upload-process-download as I was planning? Or I can run in the view function the process algorithm on the request.file and then retrieve it changed, regardless of not serving static files? Am I missing something? Does Flask has the same issue? What’s the optimal solution? Apologize me for the many doubts.

PD: I took the time to read many similar questions and seems to be possible to upload and download, but then im missing something on handling static files and what that means

Comment: Django's server itself does not serve static files but it is possible to do so through many ways one of them being through nginx and I think you mean media files (not static files) it is same for them but you upload media files not static files.

Comment: in pythonanywhere you need to specify the media path in web tab.

Comment: You are right, i was meaning media files. Tell me one more thing. Is it possible to upload / download the file from the same server that's running the app? If is possible, what is all the not serving media or static files about?